# Finding $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^2+2x-8}{x^2-4}$ without L’Hospital’s Rule

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^2+2x-8}{x^2-4}$$

I can reduce the fraction to $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x+4}{x-2}$ and I know that it has a point of discontinuity (is hole the proper term?) at $x=-2$.

However, I still have an indefinite form.  Any hints about how to solve this without L'Hospital's Rule?

Comment: At infinity, a quotient of polynomials will behave as the quotient of the term of highest degree, here it is $\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty} \frac{x}{x} = 1$.

Comment: @Antoine that comes from L'Hospital's rule.

Comment: Or from the method in the answer below: factorize the highest terms and you're done, I think

Comment: Just factorize by $x^2$ up and down.

Comment: Note: The function is continuous at $x=-2$, but not at $x=2$

Comment: @MaxBucknell Could you explain why? I thought because I could factor out $x+2$ from the numerator and denominator the hole would be at $x=-2$ because that is what still caused a problem.

Comment: @yiyi We have $(x-2)$ in both numerator and denominator so at $x = +2$ the we have $\frac{0}{0}$ which is undefined.

Comment: @yiyi Warren is right. The root of $(x + a)$ is $-a$, because $(-a + a) = 0$. When $a < 0$, $-a > 0$. In that example, $a = -2$, so when the expression is $0$, $x = -(-2) = 2$.

Comment: @MaxBucknell Know of a good primer on limits that does use the $\delta$ neighbor stuff and just explains the different cases?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: $\frac{x^{2}+2x-8}{x^{2}-4}=\frac{(x+4)(x-2)}{(x-2)(x+2)}=\frac{x+4}{x+2}=\frac{1+\frac{4}{x}}{1+\frac{2}{x}}$

Comment: From seeing your answer, could you also do $\frac{x+4-2+2}{x-2} \rightarrow \frac{x-2}{x-2}+\frac{6}{x-2}$

Comment: That works too.

Answer (score 2):

You may use this fact that when $x$ tends to infinity then for every polynomial $p(x)$ we have:

$$p(x)=a_mx^m+a_{m-1}x^{m-1}+\cdots a_1x+a_0\approx a_mx^m$$

Comment: Are you on a "break" from school right now? (i.e., a "break" from teaching, or "in-between" semesters?)

Comment: Nice. I think that's true (school/classes starting up, if not yet, then soon!)

Answer (score 2):

A somewhat different approach (we ignore the discontinuity because it is not close to the limit point):

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x+4}{x-2} \stackrel{\ y = 1/x\ }{=} \lim_{y\to0^+}\frac{\frac1y+4}{\frac1y-2} = \lim_{y\to0^+}\frac{1+4y}{1-2y}$$

where the last step is allowed since for $y \ne 0$, $\dfrac y y= 1$.

Answer (score 1):

First of all,

differentiability is sufficient, but not necessary [condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function#Differentiability_and_continuity) of continuity

and continuity [ensures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Definition_in_terms_of_limits_of_functions) the existence of a limit.

But, the given problem can handled more easily as follows:

Putting $h=\frac1x,$

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{x^2+2x-8}{x^2-4}\right)=\lim_{h\to0}\left(\frac{1+2h-8h^2}{1-4h^2}\right)=\cdots$$